# Prepopulate form with database values in gravity form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am using gravity forms to save form data to the database. It is saved successfully into the entry table. Now i want to pre-populate(prefill) saved data in the form without custom code, so that I can do update functionality of the saved data. Is there a way to do it? Please advise

Comment: There is addon from Gravity Wiz that can populate the form fields dynamically with any values. You can check this guide here - https://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/populate-anything/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using "***Populate Anything***" addons that dynamically filter and populate field choices and values with posts, users, taxonomies, terms, Gravity Forms entries, and databases. Pretty much anything!

For more information please read the article by Gravity form: [Read more](https://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/populate-anything/)!